# What is the max level in Saints Row The Third?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

What is the max level in Saints Row The Third? Because when I try to level up sometimes it will let me and sometimes won't.

Answer (score 3):

Maximum is level 50. There are some people, though, that got level 51 by playing a DLC and getting a rare bug (as mentioned by the developers) as seen [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/55230/discussions/0/611704730331449371/?insideModal=1)